# How do I delete an item within a list in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to clean out my data to perform analysis

this is the JSON sample

```
response.json() = [{'count': 19804, 
    'next': {'limit': 1, 'offset': 1}, 
    'previous': None, 

'results':
 [{'id': '334455', 
    'custom_id': '112', 
    'company': 28, 
    'company_name': 'Sunshine and Flowers', 
    'delivery_address': '34 olive beach house, #01-22, 612345', 

    'delivery_timeslot': {'lower': '2019-12-06T10:00:00Z', 'upper': '2019-12-06T13:00:00Z', 'bounds': '[)'}, 

    'sender_name': 'Edward Shine', 
    'sender_email': '', 
    'sender_contact': '91234567', 
    'removed': None, 
    'recipient_name': 'Mint Shine', 
    'recipient_contact': '91234567', 
    'notes': '', 

    'items': [{'id': 21668, 'name': 'Loose hair flowers', 'quantity': 1, 'metadata': {}, 'removed': None}, {'id': 21667, 'name': "Groom's Boutonniere", 'quantity': 1, 'metadata': {}, 'removed': None}, {'id': 21666, 'name': 'Bridal Bouquet', 'quantity': 1, 'metadata': {}, 'removed': None}], 

    'latitude': '1.28283838383642000000', 
    'longitude': '103.2828037266201000000', 
    'created': '2019-08-15T05:40:30.385467Z', 
    'updated': '2019-08-15T05:41:27.930110Z', 
    'status': 'pending', 
    'verbose_status': 'Pending', 

    'logs': [{'id': 334455, 'order': '50c402d8-7c76-45b5-b883-e2fb887a507e', 'order_custom_id': '112', 'order_delivery_address': '34 olive beach house, #01-22, 6123458', 'order_delivery_timeslot': {'lower': '2019-12-06T10:00:00Z', 'upper': '2019-12-06T13:00:00Z', 'bounds': '[)'}, 'message': 'Order was created.', 'failure_reason': None, 'success_code': None, 'success_description': None, 'created': '2019-08-15T05:40:30.431790Z', 'removed': None}, {'id': 334455, 'order': '50c402d8-7c76-45b5-b883-e2fb887a507e', 'order_custom_id': '112', 'order_delivery_address': '34 olive beach house, #01-22, 612345', 'order_delivery_timeslot': {'lower': '2019-12-06T10:00:00Z', 'upper': '2019-12-06T13:00:00Z', 'bounds': '[)'}, 'message': 'Order is pending.', 'failure_reason': None, 'success_code': None, 'success_description': None, 'created': '2019-08-15T05:40:30.433139Z', 'removed': None}], 

    'reschedule_requests': [],
    'signature': None}]]
```

I have tried this code and it works, it deletes the stated items accordingly.

```
 data = response.json()
    del data['count']
    del data['next']
    del data['previous']
    del data['results'][0]['logs']
    print(data)
```

but when I try to delete for "Items", in which I only want my "Name" to be kept, it does not work.

this is my code to delete everything in "Items" except for "Names"

```
del data['results'][0]['items']['id']['quantity']['metadata']['removed']
```

my desired output being:

```
'items': 
[{'name': 'Loose hair flowers'}, 
{''name': "Groom's Boutonniere"}, 
{'name': 'Bridal Bouquet'}]
```

how do i go about doing this?

Comment: Deleting from a data structure is in most cases less performant and the source code is harder to read. Unless your response is huge (several GBs) create a new dict/list and copy only the required elements into it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to delete data from JSON response, just iterate JSON response and get items data using list comprehension.

**Ex.**

```
items = [{'name' :x['name']} for x in data[0]['results'][0]['items']]
print(items)
```

**O/P:**

```
[{'name': 'Loose hair flowers'}, {'name': "Groom's Boutonniere"}, 
{'name': 'Bridal Bouquet'}]
```

Or if you want to change response and items kept only expected output data, then re-assign it.

```
data[0]['results'][0]['items'] = items
```